# Formatar data no datables para dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript, jquery-datatables

Gostaria de saber como formatar a data que pego do banco de dados (yyyy/mm/dd) para (dd/mm/yyyy), procurei na documentação do plugin que estou usando (DataTables) e pelo que parece só consigo mudar isso pagando pelo plugin deles que é o editor.datatables, queria saber se tem outra forma de eu formatar essa data... Não sei se vai ajudar muito mas segue o código:

```
//PESQUISA NOME
$(document).ready(function(){
//PUXA OS DADOS DA TABELA PELOS DADOS NO JSON
$('#my-table-nome').DataTable({
    ajax: 'http://localhost:8080/pesquisar/dados-tabelas',

    columns: [
        {data: 'nome',          title: 'Nome'},
        {data: 'siape',         title: 'Siape'},
        {data: 'unidade',       title: 'Unidade'},
        {data: 'funcao',        title: 'Denominação da função'},
        {data: 'codigo',        title: 'Codigo'},
        {data: 'nivel',         title: 'Nivel'},
        {data: 'tipoat',        title: 'Tipo AT'},
        {data: 'cpf',           title: 'CPF'},
        {data: 'ingresso',      title: 'Data de ingresso'},
        {data: 'portaria',      title: 'Portaria de nomeação/designação'},
        {data: 'publicacao',    title: 'Publicação de Exoneração/Dispensa'},
        {data: 'exoneracao',    title: 'Data de Exoneração/Dispensa'},
        {data: 'subnome',       title: 'Substituto Eventual'},
        {data: 'subsiape',      title: 'Siape'},
        {data: 'subcpf',        title: 'CPF'},
        {data: 'subingresso',   title: 'Data de ingresso'},
        {data: 'subexoneracao', title: 'Data de exoneração/dispensa'},
        {data: 'subpublicacao', title: 'Publicacao da nomeação/Designação'},
        {   
            title: 'Alterar',
            data: null,
            createdCell: function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
                //td: a coluna em questão
                //cellData: dados da linha inteira
                //rowData: dados da linha inteira
                //row: index da linha
                //col: index da coluna
                var href    = `/alterar?id/${cellData.id}`;
                $(td).html(`<a class="btn btn-primary" href="${href}">Editar</a>`)
            }
        }
    ],

    //CONFIGURAÇÃO DE LINGUAGEM DA TABELA
    language: {
        info: "Mostrando de _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
        infoEmpty: "Sem registros",
        emptyTable: "Nenhum registro avaliado na tabela",
        infoFiltered: "Filtrados de _MAX_ registros",
        zeroRecords: "Nenhum registro encontrado para a busca",
        lengthMenu: "Mostrando _MENU_ registros",
        paginate: {
            first: '<<',
            last: '>>',
            previous: '<',
            next: '>'
        }
    }
});

//CRIA A COLUNA DE ALTERAÇÃO
$('#my-table-nome thead th').each(function() {

    var title = $(this).text();
    if(title == 'Nome'){
        $(this).append('<br /><input type="text" id="my-input-nome" size="50" placeholder="Digite aqui o nome do Servidor" />');
    }
});

var table = $('#my-table-nome').DataTable();

// APLICA A BUSCA
$('#my-input-nome').on( 'keyup', function () {
    table.column(0).search( this.value ).draw();
});
```

});

Comment: E como ficou a solução???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode manipular datas utilizando o próprio javascript, desta forma:

```js
let dataTabela = new Date();
let _localizacao = 'pt-BR'
let _param = {
 year: 'numeric', 
 month: '2-digit', 
 day: '2-digit' 
};

console.log(dataTabela.toLocaleDateString( _localizacao, _param ));
```

Outra boa alternativa seria uso de uma lib como o - https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolver com o moment js